# Pandas generate rows multiplicatively based on values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two tables in separate csv files.

**Rad**

```
ID/Key  ID  RowKey  RadKey  RadStart    RadStop
 A16    A1    6       4     1/1/2018    2/1/2018
 A16    A1    6       5     3/1/2018    4/1/2018
 A17    A1    7       6     4/1/2018    5/1/2018
 A17    A1    7       7     5/1/2018    6/1/2018
```

**Mani**

```
ID/Key  ID   RowKey   Order Date     Order ID
A16     A1     6       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0075
A16     A1     6       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0076
A16     A1     6       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0077
A17     A1     7       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0075
A17     A1     7       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0077
```

I need to write a new file which, for every `RadKey`, write the entire `RadKey` row `n` number of times, where `n` is the number of times the `ID/Key` pair appear in `Mani` multiplied by the number of `RadKeys` for that `ID/Key` pair. The newly generated file should include the `Order Date` and `Order ID` from `Mani` for each row.

**Generated file**

```
ID  RowKey  RadKey  RadStart    RadStop    Order Date     Order ID
A1  6        4      1/1/2018    2/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0075
A1  6        4      1/1/2018    2/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0076
A1  6        4      1/1/2018    2/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0077
A1  6        5      3/1/2018    4/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0075
A1  6        5      3/1/2018    4/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0076
A1  6        5      3/1/2018    4/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0077
A1  7        6      4/1/2018    5/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0075
A1  7        6      4/1/2018    5/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0077
A1  7        7      5/1/2018    6/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0075
A1  7        7      5/1/2018    6/1/2018    1/1/2015    1234-USF-0077
```

**Notes**

`RadKeys` are unique across all `ID/Key` pairs

`Order IDs` can repeat for the same `ID/Key` pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a cartesian product using `merge` on a uniform key assigned to both files.

```
from io import StringIO

radfile = StringIO("""ID/Key  ID  RowKey  RadKey  RadStart    RadStop
 A16    A1    6       4     1/1/2018    2/1/2018
 A16    A1    6       5     3/1/2018    4/1/2018
 A17    A1    7       6     4/1/2018    5/1/2018
 A17    A1    7       7     5/1/2018    6/1/2018""")

manifile = StringIO("""ID/Key  ID   RowKey   Order Date     Order ID
A16     A1     6       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0075
A16     A1     6       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0076
A16     A1     6       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0077
A17     A1     7       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0075
A17     A1     7       1/1/2015   1234-USF-0077""")

rad_df = pd.read_csv(radfile, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
mani_df = pd.read_csv(manifile, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

df_out = rad_df.assign(key=1).merge(mani_df.assign(key=1))
df_out.to_csv("outfile.csv", index=False, sep='\t')
!type outfile.csv
```

Output:

```
ID/Key  ID  RowKey  RadKey  RadStart    RadStop key Order Date  Order ID
A16 A1  6   4   1/1/2018    2/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0075
A16 A1  6   4   1/1/2018    2/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0076
A16 A1  6   4   1/1/2018    2/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0077
A16 A1  6   5   3/1/2018    4/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0075
A16 A1  6   5   3/1/2018    4/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0076
A16 A1  6   5   3/1/2018    4/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0077
A17 A1  7   6   4/1/2018    5/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0075
A17 A1  7   6   4/1/2018    5/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0077
A17 A1  7   7   5/1/2018    6/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0075
A17 A1  7   7   5/1/2018    6/1/2018    1   1/1/2015    1234-USF-0077
```

Comment: When I open `outfile.csv`, I receive the following: `The file format and extension of "outfile.csv" don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?` Then: `Excel has detected that "outfile.csv" is a SYLK file, but cannot load it. Either the file has errors or it is not a SYLK file format. Click OK to try to open the file in a different format.` When I open the file, it appears to be correct, but I am concerned about the warnings. Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.alunr.com/excel-csv-import-returns-an-sylk-file-format-error/

Comment: Wow, such a simple fix for a cryptic issue. Everything looks great now, thanks so much!